# Python - MIDI mapping/binding

Tags: python

Всем добра!
У меня есть usb MIDI controller, я хочу управлять виртуальной средой по средствам usb/midi. Не имею понятия что для этого есть вообще. Гуглить пробовал, не очень доволен результатом поиска.
Подскажите пожалуйста приличную(ые) библиотеку для MIDI. Интересно что есть для этого.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня есть usb MIDI controller, я хочу управлять виртуальной средой по средствам usb/midi. Не имею понятия что для этого есть вообще. Гуглить пробовал, не очень доволен результатом поиска. Решил спросить в сообществе.

Answer (score 0):

Уже нашел pyrtmidi, намерен провести тест
https://github.com/patrickkidd/pyrtmidi